# Fileobserver for facebook picture upload in android

Tags: android, fileobserver

In my android application, I am running a background Service and the service runs some code if a user takes a picture from facebook application. The service is doing that by using fileobserver to observe **storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Facebook/** folder. If this folder path Different than mine in different devices, how can I find The correct folder path in my application?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain in detail :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct  folder path  using the `Environment` class like:

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Facebook");
```